# How can I create a "playlist" of midi files on a raspberry pi?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspbian, midi

I am trying to create a looping playlist of midi files on a raspberry pi for a christmas light display, i have a collection of midi files and I know that i can play them indivually with the command

```
aplaymidi -p 14 /home/user/Music/myMidi.mid
```

is there a way I can create a C script that would cycle between songs and restart once all are done?

I have looked around for info on Midi files and their interactions with C but have had little luck...

Comment: C would not be my language of choice for running command-line programs, have you considered using a bash/shell script?

Comment: I'm open to that, I am just unsure how to approach it as I have never written in those languages before, I thought I could get the length of the midi file, play it, wait for the length, and then play the next.

Comment: `aplaymidi` returns after finishing the file, so you could make a script that just calls `aplaymidi` over and over with different files. How are you keeping track of the songs to play? Do you have a text file with the filenames of all the songs to play?

Comment: I have a list of files to play, that sounds like it should work just over and over, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty script to loop over the lines of a text file and play the midi files inside:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

song_names=$1     #save the filename of the list of songs
while : # infinite loop
do
    while IFS="" read -r f || [ -n "$f" ]; do  # read a line, even if missing terminating line feed
        echo "Playing $f"
        aplaymidi -p 14 "$f"
    done < "$song_names"   # read from song names file
done
```

There's probably ways to make it more efficient (only read the file once, for example) but this should get you started.